# boost::variant and function overload resolution

Tags: c++, boost

The following code doesn't compile:

```cpp
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
class D {};

using v1 = boost::variant<A, B>;
using v2 = boost::variant<C, D>;

int f(v1 const&) {
    return 0;
}
int f(v2 const&) {
    return 1;
}
int main() {
    return f(A{});
}
```

both gcc and clang complains with:

```
test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test1.cpp:18:17: error: call of overloaded ‘f(A)’ is ambiguous
     return f(A{});
                 ^
test1.cpp:18:17: note: candidates are:
test1.cpp:11:5: note: int f(const v1&)
 int f(v1 const&) {
     ^
test1.cpp:14:5: note: int f(const v2&)
 int f(v2 const&) {
```

Given that is not possible to construct a `v2` object from an `A` instance why the compiler gives the same priority to both functions during the overload resolution?

Comment: `variant` has implicit templated converting constructors. If those aren't adequately protected with `enable_if` this could be the result.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the constructor

```
template<typename T>
variant(const T&)
```

of `boost::variant`. The code below reproduces the problem without all the magic:

```
struct C {};

struct A {
  A(const C&) {}

  template<typename T>
  A(const T&) {}
};
struct B {
  template<typename T>
  B(const T&) {}
};

int f(const A&) {
    return 0;
}
int f(const B&) {
    return 1;
}
int main() {
  return f(C{});
}
```

I think the `variant` constructor should only be enabled if the
argument is actually convertible to the arguments, you might want to
raise this as a bug.

Comment: Note that this is the same problem `std::function` has

Comment: @Yakk Interesting. I never ran into this issue. Is there a DR for it?

Comment: @pmr I do not know: but it would be so much cleaner post `requires` I would be tempted to wait.

Answer (score 3):

A pragmatic approach, short of fixing the conversion with explicit conversion with proper SFINAE (I don't think it can be done elegantly outside the Boost Variant library), could be this:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ed3698a197fc082)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
class D {};

using v1 = boost::variant<A, B>;
using v2 = boost::variant<C, D>;

namespace detail {
    struct F : boost::static_visitor<int> {
        template <typename... T>
        int operator()(boost::variant<T...> const& v) const {
            return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
        }

        int operator()(A) const { return 0; }
        int operator()(B) const { return 0; }
        int operator()(C) const { return 1; }
        int operator()(D) const { return 1; }
    } _f;
}

template <typename T>
int f(T const& t) {
    return detail::F()(t);
}

int main() {
    std::cout <<  f(A{})   << "\n";
    std::cout <<  f(B{})   << "\n";
    std::cout <<  f(C{})   << "\n";
    std::cout <<  f(D{})   << "\n";
    std::cout <<  f(v1{})  << "\n";
    std::cout <<  f(v2{})  << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
0
0
1
1
0
1
```

The assumption is that `f(T)` always returns the same value for the same `T` even if it is the member of more than one variant